# What is the best and the fastest way to delete large directory containing thousands of files (in ubuntu)

Tags: linux, bash

As I know the commands like

```
find <dir> -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

are not the best variant to remove large amount of files (total files, including subfolder). It works good if you have small amount of files, but if you have 10+ mlns files in subfolders, it can hang a server.

Does anyone know any specific linux commands to solve this problem?

Comment: What needs to be quick, creating space or getting the directory out of the way. If the second, them `mv` it (very quick), then delete it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

local LOCKFILE=/tmp/rmHugeNumberOfFiles.lock

# this process gets ultra-low priority
ionice -c2 -n7 -p $$ > /dev/null
if [ $? ]; then
    echo "Could not set disk IO priority. Exiting..."
    exit
fi
renice +19 -p $$ > /dev/null
if [ $? ]; then
    echo "Could not renice process. Exiting..."
    exit
fi

# check if there's an instance running already. If so--exit
if [ -e ${LOCKFILE} ] && kill -0 `cat ${LOCKFILE}`; then
    echo "An instance of this script is already running."
    exit
fi

# make sure the lockfile is removed when we exit. Then: claim the lock
trap "command rm -f -- $LOCKFILE; exit" INT TERM EXIT
echo $$ > $LOCKFILE

# also create a tempfile, and make sure that's removed too upon exit
tmp=$(tempfile) || exit
trap "command rm -f -- '$tmp'" INT TERM EXIT



# ----------------------------------------
# option 1
# ----------------------------------------
# find your specific files
find "$1" -type f [INSERT SPECIFIC SEARCH PATTERN HERE] > "$tmp"
cat $tmp | rm 

# ----------------------------------------
# option 2
# ----------------------------------------
command rm -r "$1"



# remove the lockfile, tempfile
command rm -f -- "$tmp" $LOCKFILE
```

This script starts by setting its own process priority and diskIO priority to very low values, to ensure other running processes are as unaffected as possible.

Then it makes sure that it is the ONLY such process running.

The core of the script is really up to your preference. You can use `rm -r` if you are sure that the whole dir can be deleted indesciminately (option 2), or you can use `find` for more specific file deletion (option 1, possibly using command line options "$2" and onw. for convenience).

In the implementation above, Option 1 (`find`) first outputs everything to a tempfile, so that the `rm` function is only called *once* instead of after each file found by `find`. When the number of files is indeed huge, this can amount to a significant time saving. On the downside, the size of the tempfile may become an issue, but this is only likely if you're deleting literally billions of files, plus, because the diskIO has such low priority, using a tempfile followed by a single `rm` may in total be slower than using the `find (...) -exec rm {} \;` option. As always, you should experiment a bit to see what best fits your needs.

> EDIT: As suggested by user946850, you can also skip the whole tempfile and use `find (...) -print0 | xargs -0 rm`. This has a larger memory footprint, since all full paths to all matching files will be inserted in RAM until the `find` command is completely finished. On the upside: there is no additional file IO due to writes to the tempfile. Which one to choose depends on your use-case.

Answer (score 8):

It may seem strange but:

```
$ rm -rf <dir>
```

Comment: It would be at this point that someone should tell you to beware.  The `-f` option forces the delete with no prompt - executing this in the wrong place can cause some serious havoc on your system...  Test it and get used to the command before executing it on your server.

Comment: This is best for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in August 2017.

Answer (score 1):

The `-r` (recursive) switch removes everything below a directory, too -- including subdirectories. (Your command does not remove the directories, only the files.)

You can also speed up the `find` approach:

```
find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: xargs will take files one group at a time, and even wait for processes to finish first. It maybe more efficient than `find ... -exec rm {} \;` because that executes a process for each file. The problem with xargs is that it doesn't handle whitespace, but the `-print0` and the `-0` flags handle that issue.

Answer (score 1):

The previous commands are good.

`rm -rf directory/` also works faster for billion of files in one folder. I tried that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried every one of these commands, but problem I had was that the deletion process was locking the disk, and since no other processes could access it, there was a big pileup of processes trying to access the disk making the problem worse. Run "iotop" and see how much disk IO your process is using.

Here's the python script that solved my problem. It deletes 500 files at a time, then takes a 2 second break to let the other processes do their business, then continues.

```
import os, os.path
import time

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/dir/to/delete/files'):
    i = 0
    file_num = 0
    for f in files:
        fullpath = os.path.join(root, f)
        i = i + 1
        file_num = file_num + 1
        os.remove(fullpath)
        if i%500 == 1:
            time.sleep(2)
            print "Deleted %i files" % file_num
```

Hope this helps some people.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to deal with space limit issue on a very large file tree (in my case many perforce branches), that sometimes **being hanged while running** the find and delete process -

Here's a script that I schedule daily to **find all directories with specific file** ("ChangesLog.txt"), 
and then **Sort all directories** found that are **older than** 2 days, and Remove the first matched directory (each schedule there could be a new match):

```
bash -c "echo @echo Creating Cleanup_Branch.cmd on %COMPUTERNAME% - %~dp0 > Cleanup_Branch.cmd"
bash -c "echo -n 'bash -c \"find ' >> Cleanup_Branch.cmd"
rm -f dirToDelete.txt
rem cd. > dirToDelete.txt 
bash -c "find .. -maxdepth 9 -regex ".+ChangesLog.txt" -exec echo {} >> dirToDelete.txt \; & pid=$!; sleep 100; kill $pid "
sed -e 's/\(.*\)\/.*/\1/' -e 's/^./"&/;s/.$/&" /' dirToDelete.txt | tr '\n' ' ' >> Cleanup_Branch.cmd
bash -c "echo -n '-maxdepth 0 -type d -mtime +2 | xargs -r ls -trd | head -n1 | xargs -t rm -Rf' >> Cleanup_Branch.cmd"
bash -c 'echo -n \" >> Cleanup_Branch.cmd'
call Cleanup_Branch.cmd
```

Note the requirements:

1. Deleting only those directories with "ChangesLog.txt", since other old directories should not be deleted.
2. Calling the OS commands in **cygwin directly**, since otherwise it used Windows default commands.
3. Collecting the directories to delete into external text file, in order to **save find results**, since sometimes the find process has hanged.
4. Setting a **timeout to the find process by using & background process that being killed after 100 seconds**.
5. Sorting the directories oldest first, for the delete priority.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reasonably modern version of find (4.2.3 or greater) you can use the -delete flag.

```
find <dir> -type f -delete
```

If you have version 4.2.12 or greater you can take advantage of xargs style command line stacking via the `\+` -exec modifier. This way you don't run a separate copy of `/bin/rm` for every file.

```
find <dir> -type f -exec rm {} \+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like delete tons of files as soon as possible, try this:

`find . -type f -print0 | xargs -P 0 -0 rm -f`

Note the `-P` option will make `xargs` use processes as many as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
mv large_folder /tmp/.
sudo reboot
```

Call to mv is fast - it just modifies labels. System reboot will clear the /tmp folder (mount it again?)  in the fastest way possible.

Comment: This is likely to be very slow. if /tmp is on a different file system, which is often the case, the mv operation requires actually copying all the files. And then there's the time to wait for that rather unnecessary reboot.

Comment: yes, you are right rsync is a better option

Comment: I don't see the advantage of rsync, to be honest. On Linux and *nix systems, `rm -rf <dir>` is done recursively with minimal state information. I'm pretty sure it's the most efficient solution there is. Windows is a different story, but for Ubuntu it seems to me the solution is clear and simple.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What makes this approach the best and fastest?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a empty directory and RSYNC it to the directory which you need to empty.
You will avoid time out and memory out issue

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an answer really needs to demonstrate the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean (for example, you didn't mention the `--delete` flag, but that will be apparent in your answer). Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: Ditto.  I would like to see this work.   PLEASE show how.